# Passing value to function throws PSInvalidCastException

Tags: powershell, function, types, parameters, casting

I've been dealing with this for the better part of two days and I just don't understand where the exception is coming from. I wrote a simple function to check if an integer is in a given range:

```
function Validate-UserInput {
    param(
        [Int32]$Input,
        [Int32]$LwLimit,
        [Int32]$UpLimit
    )
    return $Input -in $LwLimit..$UpLimit
}
```

I call it as such:

```
$choice = -1
[Int32]::TryParse((Read-Host "`r`n`tEnter choice"), [ref]$choice)
Validate-UserInput -Input $choice -LwLimit 0 -UpLimit 3
```

When I run the segment, it throws the following error:

```
Validate-UserInput : Cannot convert the "System.Collections.ArrayList+ArrayListEnumeratorSimple" value of type "System.Collections.ArrayList+ArrayListEnumerato
rSimple" to type "System.Int32".
At D:\Temp\test234.ps1:15 char:1
+ Validate-UserInput -Input $value -LwLimit 0 -UpLimit 3
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Validate-UserInput], PSInvalidCastException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException,Validate-UserInput
```

No type of casting works, it always ends up as the same error. Checking the type of the `$value` variable right before the function is called confirms it's an `Int32`.

When the type for the `$Input` variable in the param block is removed, I can see in the debugger that it's type is `System.Collections.IEnumerator`, with a type present in the param block the debugger doesn't even enter the function.

The only thing that lets the script run to the end is setting the `$Input` variable type to `[string]`, but that just returns True for every value typed in and the debugger still shows it's type as `IEnumerator`, despite a call to `GetType()` right before the return statement saying that it's a `String`

Needless to say, I am throroughly confused as to what is going on here, I've never encountered a situation like this before and it's an extremely simple code block that should be executing without any fanfare. Can anyone offer any insight?

Comment: Don't use ```$input``` as a function parameter name - it's a reserved "Automatic variable" variable in PowerShell (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.4). Rename it ```$Value``` or similar and your function should work fine.